# How to create a trigger that checks if a value in 2 fields is present and if it is change it to something else

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I am new to db, and trying to create a trigger that checks some fields in a table for a value and if the value is present than it updates it to something else. These are my thoughts so far.

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_Load
AFTER UPDATE ON PODIUM_CORE
FOR EACH ROW ( WHERE PODIUM_CORE.SNAME OR PODIUM_CORE.INTERNAL = "LOAD")
UPDATE PODIUM_CORE.SNAME = "LOAD_GENERAL";

EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_Load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) a trigger in Postgres consists of a trigger *function* and a trigger definition.

String constants are written in single quotes in SQL, `"LOAD"` refers to a column or table name, `'LOAD'` is a string (character) constant.

If you want to change something using a trigger, you should use a `BEFORE` trigger and simply assign the new value to the record. Running a separate DML statement for that is the wrong approach in Postgres.

You didn't really give us much to go with, but I assume you are looking for something like this:

Define the trigger **function**:

```sql
create function check_load() 
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.sname := 'LOAD_GENERAL';
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then create the trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_check_Load
  BEFORE UPDATE ON podium_core
  FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN sname = 'LOAD' OR internal 'LOAD'
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_load();
```

It's more efficient to only fire the trigger when the specified values are provided, rather than firing the trigger always and check for the value inside the trigger.

---

But if you want to do that check inside the trigger function it would be something like this:

```sql
create function check_load() 
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  if (new.sname = 'LOAD' or new.internal = 'LOAD') then 
    new.sname := 'LOAD_GENERAL';
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_check_Load
  BEFORE UPDATE ON podium_core
  FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_load();
```